# Parsing a table from PDF with PHP

Tags: php, pdf, timetable

I've been trying to think this out but I can't get it quite working. So I was thinking about "importing" (upload & preprocess / standardize data) a PDF standard formatted timetable in PHP.

Already tried several libraries (smalot/pdfparser, gufy/pdftohtml-php, tecnickcom/tc-lib-pdf-parser and some small classes) for reading PDF, but all I seem to get is simple text and at most X Y position and content of the paragraph. I am currenty trying to somewhat to organize data in a (x, y, content) but I am really looking for a way to get a table like structure in HTML / XML.

Converting the PDF to XLSX results inconsistent positioning of elements in the timetable. Maybe a better format to convert it to then interpret in PHP.

Comment: We use `pdftotext -layout -nopgbrk` to turn the PDF into text and then we look for expected content to find our bearings in the document.

Answer (score 0):

But PDF is build like that: some portion of text and (x, y) coordinates. Line, rectangle and (x, y) coordinates. It isn't like html with tables, headers or any logical structure. Parsing PDF is more like OCR of printouts, there is no structure.

Comment: I might have omitted that :-?. Thank you.